# openjdk-7-jre installed, but no binaries

Tags: 14.04, java, openjdk

I executed

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

and the package seems to have installed cleanly, but /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/ was empty except for the program policytool

I installed openjdk-7-jdk as well, and /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/ was properly populated, but /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/ remained empty.

So now I'm in a state where I have javac, jar, javadoc, etc. but no java

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
policytool*
$ find /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ -name java -print
$
```

`dpkg -L openjdk-7-jre` indicates that there is no java executable in the package. `dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` indicates that it *should* be there.

Have I corrupted a database somewhere? How can I fix it?

I've tried the obvious such as disabling ppas in Software Sources, executing `apt-get clean` and `apt-get update`, `apt-get purge openjdk-7-jre` and so forth.

---

Update: I executed these commands:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

This is all well and good, but I **need** to run openjdk 7, not the Oracle version. I'm building Android and the build system is locked to a specific  version.

This all worked until yesterday when a `sudo update-alternatives --config java` command went wrong and I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the openjdk7 package and it wouldn't reinstall properly.

Comment: try executing these commands:
which java
java -version and then let us know.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: More ... I've downloaded the .deb file directly and opened it up. It definitely contains the files I think it should contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files you're looking for aren't in `openjdk-7-jre`; they're in `openjdk-7-jre-headless`.

The `openjdk-7-jre-headless` package installs the following list of files (from Ubuntu 15.10 amd64 installation):

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/jvm
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/THIRD_PARTY_README
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/currency.data
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_LinkDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_MoveNoDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_LinkNoDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_MoveDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_CopyNoDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/invalid32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/motif_CopyDrop32x32.gif
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jvm.hprof.txt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/javazic.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/classlist
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/local_policy.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/PYCC.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/LINEAR_RGB.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/sRGB.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/GRAY.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/cmm/CIEXYZ.pf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libinstrument.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2krb5.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/headless
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/Xusage.txt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsdt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libunpack.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libicedtea-sound.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnpt.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libhprof.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsound.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2gss.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjaas_unix.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjavalcms.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pcsc.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libmlib_image.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libsaproc.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libdt_socket.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libsctp.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libattach.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjavajpeg.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg-default
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj2pkcs11.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava_crw_demo.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjsig.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjdwp.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/meta-index
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jar.binfmt
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jexec
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/compilefontconfig.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/pack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/tnameserv
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/servertool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/unpack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java-rmi.cgi
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/JAVA_HOME
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/NEWS.IcedTea.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/README.alternatives
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/AUTHORS.IcedTea
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/copyright
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-7-jre-headless/README.IcedTea.gz
/usr/share/binfmts
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openjdk-7-jre-headless
/etc
/etc/java-7-openjdk
/etc/java-7-openjdk/fontconfig.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/images
/etc/java-7-openjdk/images/cursors
/etc/java-7-openjdk/images/cursors/cursors.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/sound.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/logging.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
/etc/java-7-openjdk/accessibility.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/net.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/swing.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/tz.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/calendars.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/flavormap.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/psfontj2d.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/security
/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/nss.cfg
/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.policy
/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.security
/etc/java-7-openjdk/management
/etc/java-7-openjdk/management/jmxremote.password
/etc/java-7-openjdk/management/management.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/management/jmxremote.access
/etc/java-7-openjdk/management/snmp.acl
/etc/java-7-openjdk/content-types.properties
/etc/java-7-openjdk/psfont.properties.ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/rmiregistry.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/pack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/orbd.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/rmid.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/servertool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/unpack200.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/tnameserv.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/fontconfig.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/images/cursors/cursors.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sound.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/logging.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/accessibility.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/net.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/swing.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/tz.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/calendars.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/flavormap.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/psfontj2d.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/nss.cfg
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.policy
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/management.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management/snmp.acl
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/content-types.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/psfont.properties.ja
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/zi
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/docs
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/orbd
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/tnameserv
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/servertool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this one "accepted". The thing is, "openjdk-7-jre-headless" isn't an option that Ubuntu Software Center presents to me. (It also doesn't present any form of "openjdk-7-jdk" which I also need). I Just solved the problem myself 30 seconds ago by downloading the .deb file and using `dpkg` to install it.

Comment: You do know there is `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`, right?

Comment: This is part of my love-hate relationship with Linux. How is any ordinary user supposed to figure out how to install Java on their system?

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` is exactly what I've been doing. That part works fine. It was the jre I couldn't install. And again, how was an ordinary user supposed to figure that out?

Comment: Yay! My build is working again. I only lost half a day. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The software center probably just lists it as "Java" or "Java Headless". This is partially why I don't use the Software Center myself. On the other hand, installing the JDK should automatically install the JRE (both headless and non-headless), so I'm not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: The search for "headless" seems to have found it. The search for "java" did not. I'm starting to suspect that Software Center's search function is broken. Anyway, my builds *and* Android Studio are all working now, so I'm happy.

Comment: OMG, what the hell, why does the non-`headless` package even exist!